Ellegaard's sequence is not starting, how to get Occam's Razor trophy?
I'm trying to get Occam's Razor trophy.
I copied my old save file, restarted chapter 6 of episode 1, but I always get Axel's sequence in episode 2 despite having chosen Olivia at the end of episode 1.
How can I force the game to start Ellegaard's sequence and let me complete Occam's Razor trophy?
I'm on PS4, it that counts.

I chose an empty save file from scratch and selected chapter 2.
The game explained that all my uncompleted story will be generated, this luckily let me start the correct Olivia's sequence.
As explained in the walkthrough, this seems random:

you can choose a new save file, start episode 2 and hope that the random choices pick the other person for you.

